# Unbounded Set seems bounded

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, compactness

The term "unbounded set" is usually defined as such: if a set is not bounded, then it is unbounded.

This definition, while having its own merits, is somewhat weak. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, the set $\{(x,y)|1<x<2\}$ is an unbounded set, even though it is actually bounded by two lines: $x=1$ and $x=2$.

"Bounded by a hyperplane" is defined in the fashion of convex analysis: a set S is bounded by a hyperplane $\langle \cdot,v\rangle=c$ if all points in S are at the same side of the hyperplane:

$\langle x,v\rangle\leq c $ $\forall x\in S$ or $\langle x,v\rangle\geq c$  $\forall x\in S$.

Now we are going to have a stronger definition called "strongly unbounded":

A set S is strongly unbounded if S is not bounded by two non-intersecting lines at the different side.

Does this definition make sense to you? Anyone defined this object before? Are there any interesting properties?

---

Precise definitions added! Thank you for all your comments. Any answers are welcome; no need to be complete.

Comment: What if your definition of "bounded by" if it is satisfied by the first set you define? Be precise.

Comment: The set you give is not bounded by anyone's definition.  Being bounded on the left and right doesn't make it bounded.

Comment: I think your issue is that you want the set to be unbounded in every direction. In the example you gave, it is unbounded as y increases, but not as x increases.

Comment: " even though it is actually bounded by two lines: x=1 and x=2. "  I would argue that the english language phrase "bounded by two lines" is highly inaccurate and clearly incorrect and and wrong.  Intuitively the terms in this set can have magnitudes larger than any finite limit.  To my mind that is "clearly" unbounded.

Comment: You have to understand what the usual definition of bounded refers to in order to understand the nuances of it. Try to think of "boundedness" as deciding whether you can fit something inside a circle with finite radius (you'll have to make the necessary changes for other dimensions, of course); if you can, then it is bounded, and if you cannot, then the set is not bounded. In the set you gave, what you *can* say is that the set is contained in a set of the form $A\times B$ where $A,B\subseteq \Bbb R$ and at least one of $A$ or $B$ is bounded (in this example, it'd be the set $A$).

Comment: "Does this definition make sense to you?"  Yes, but it's pointless.  Consider $[0,\infty)$.  It's bounded on the left but not the right.  ANd (x,y) so that $x < 2$ and $y < 7 $ and $x+y < 100$ is bounded by three lines.  Or $\{(x,y)|y > 2x^2 -3\}$.  That's bounded by a parabola.  *NONE* of these are interesting or relevant. "Are there any interesting properties?"  I very strongly doubt it.

Comment: The standard definition of a bounded $S\subset \Bbb R^2$, with respect to the Euclidean (Cartesian) metric, is that there exists $r\in \Bbb R^+$ such that $S\subset \{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le r\}$. What you are describing is a subset of the region $bounded$ $by$ 2 parallel lines

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry I forgot to include the definition of "bounding hyperplane" (commonly accepted in the convex analysis). The first set in my description are bounded by two hyperplanes by this definition.

Comment: @fleablood I was referring the definition in convex analysis: bounded by and bounding